# While loop not breaking(python)

Tags: python, while-loop, break

Here based on the conditions value of *cows* is set. And if *cows* is equal to *4* then the while loop should break.
But here *break* is treated as if it is not present.

```
import random

r = random.randint
def get_num():
 return "{0}{1}{2}{3}".format(r(1, 9), r(1, 9), r(1, 9), r(1, 9))

n = get_num()
print(n)
n = [z for z in str(n)]

def game():
    cows = 0
    bulls = 0
    print()

    usr_num = [i for i in input("enter:\n")]
    usr_set = set(usr_num)

    while True:
        for x in usr_set:
            if usr_num.count(x) >= n.count(x):
                cows += n.count(x)
                bulls += usr_num.count(x) - n.count(x)
            elif usr_num.count(x) < n.count(x):
                cows += usr_num.count(x)
                bulls += n.count(x) - usr_num.count(x)

        print("cows: ", cows, "   bulls: ", bulls)

        if cows == 4:
            print("correct!")
            break
        else:
            game()

game()
```

When *cows* = *4*, *correct* is printed but *break* is not showing its effect

And if we slightly change the code.
In place of *cows* if we put *4*(If statement)

```
def game():
    cows = 0
    bulls = 0
    print()

    usr_num = [i for i in input("enter:\n")]
    usr_set = set(usr_num)

    while True:
        for x in usr_set:
            if usr_num.count(x) >= n.count(x):
                cows += n.count(x)
                bulls += usr_num.count(x) - n.count(x)
            elif usr_num.count(x) < n.count(x):
                cows += usr_num.count(x)
                bulls += n.count(x) - usr_num.count(x)

        print("cows: ", cows, "   bulls: ", bulls)

        if 4 == 4:
            print("correct!")
            break
        else:
            game()

game()
```

Then *break* is working.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! `NameError: name 'n' is not defined` please [edit] your question to include enough code so we can replicate the problem. Please include some sample input as well.

Comment: You are in several loops at the same time due to recursion.

Comment: `game()` sets a pair of *local* variables, not the variables used in your loop. (Or is there a problem with the indentation in your code?)

Comment: We cannot replicate your problem because you haven't supplied a [mcve]: if you want help you must supply the missing code as well as valid input that produces the problem. Please also check **very** carefully to ensure the indentation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are recursing each time you do another round, which means when you `break`, you only end up breaking out of the last recursion.

Instead of using tail recursion, try moving the `while True:`

```
def game():
    while True:
        cows = 0
        bulls = 0
        print()

        usr_num = [i for i in input("enter:\n")]
        usr_set = set(usr_num)

        for x in usr_set:
            if usr_num.count(x) >= n.count(x):
                cows += n.count(x)
                bulls += usr_num.count(x) - n.count(x)
            elif usr_num.count(x) < n.count(x):
                cows += usr_num.count(x)
                bulls += n.count(x) - usr_num.count(x)

        print("cows: ", cows, "   bulls: ", bulls)

        if cows == 4:
            print("correct!")
            break
```

This way we don't recurse, so our break works as you expect: see [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SmugIndigoInterfaces)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running your code and here are more problems with your script than just the while loop.

But try this little script to learn how a while loop works:

```
# While loop test

i=0
j=5
while True:
    if i >= j:
        break
    else:
        print(f"{i} < {j}")
        i +=1
```

Hope this helps. have a play.